# How to build the url with filter params in RTK Query of this format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, url-parameters, rtk-query

I struggle making the url to fetch data with filters. Backend REST api is built in .Net.
The url to filter items has this format:

> *BASE_URL/ENDPOINT?Technologies=some-id&Complexities=0&Complexities=1&page=1&pageSize=3*

**Technologies and Complexities can repeat x times with different values.**

RTK Query provides a query function, but it doesn't build up the url in the way i need.

```js
export const apiService = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'apiService',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: BASE_URL }),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getAllQuizzes: build.query<ApiResponse, QueryProps>({
      query: ({ Technologies, Complexities, page, pageSize }) => {
        return ({
          url: ENDPOINT,
          params: {
            Technologies,
            Complexities,
            page,
            pageSize, 
          }
        })
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```

Im using mui async autocomplete component to pick multiple filters. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RTK Query only uses the object signature of the `URLSearchParams` constructor function by default.

For you, that will not work.

Theoretically, you could pass in your own pre-populated `URLSearchParams` object in there (but this is not a guarantee for future versions and not indicated by the TypeScript types), or could just omit the `params` step altogether, building the full url yourself:

```js
   getAllQuizzes: build.query<ApiResponse, QueryProps>({
      query: ({ Technologies, Complexities, page, pageSize }) => {
        const params = new URLSearchParams({ page, pageSize })
        for (const tech of Technologies) {
          params.append('Technologies', tech)
        }
        for (const comp of Complexities) {
          params.append('Complexities', comp )
        }
        return ({
          url: ENDPOINT+'?'+params.toString(),
        })
      },
    }),
```

Alternatively, you could also keep your existing code and specify a custom `paramsSerializer` function - for example the [`query-string`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string) library:

```js
import queryString from 'query-string'

//...
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl,
    paramsSerializer: (params: Record<string, unknown>) =>
        queryString.stringify(params, { arrayFormat: 'none' }),
})
```

Comment: Absolutely stoked to find this answer from you @phry, nothing like a solution from the horses mouth ;P